# How do I redirect to another page in my react app after changing the redux store state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a react project where I am using redux to manage state. I have a reducer (`authReducer`) I am using to set a boolean value for (`isAuthenticated`) and a protected route component (`ProtectedRoute.js`) where I check the state of this value. If set to false, then I redirect the client to a login component (`Login.js`). If (`isAuthenticated`) is set to true, I should be able to browse all links. The routing itself is managed by a component (`Routes.js`).

**authReducer.js**

```
import * as actionTypes from '../actions/actionTypes'

const initialState = {
    isAuthenticated: false
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.LOGIN:
            console.log('[authReducer.js] case: LOGIN')
            return {
                ...state, isAuthenticated: true
            }
        default:
            return initialState
    }
}
```

**ProtectedRoute.js**

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ ...props }) =>
    props.authReducer ? <Route {...props}/> : <Redirect to="/login"/>;

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        authReducer: state.authReducer.isAuthenticated
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProtectedRoute);
```

**Routes.js**

```
class Routes extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
                    <ProtectedRoute path="/" exact component={Dashboard} />
                    <ProtectedRoute path="/Dashboard" exact component={Dashboard} />
                    <ProtectedRoute path="/About" exact component={About} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

**Login.js**

```
class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <h1>Login</h1>
                <Button onClick={() => this.props.onLogin(this.props.authReducer)}>Login</Button>
                <Button>Logout</Button>
            </Container>


        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        authReducer: state.authReducer.isAuthenticated
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onLogin: () => dispatch({type: actionTypes.LOGIN})
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

**index.js**

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    authReducer: authReducer
});
const store = createStore(rootReducer)

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <Provider store={store}>
          <App />
      </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I'm having an issue setting the `isAuthenticated` boolean value to true, and then browsing the protected routes. The routes I set up are still protected and I'm not 100% sure why. I'm new to react so any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it log `console.log('[authReducer.js] case: LOGIN')` in your code? BTW you need to use `redux-persist` to keep users logged in even after a refresh.

Comment: It does log  `console.log('[authReducer.js] case: LOGIN')` so the switch case is being hit when a user hits the login button.

Comment: To see what's really going on, you can use `redux dev tools` chrome extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en). And you should also change your store according to this npm package => https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-devtools-extension

Comment: thanks for suggesting that tool, that;s a helpful debugger. I'm seeing in the extension that the authReducer is in fact setting the `isAuthenticated` state to `true`.

Comment: isAuthenticated is coming as true or not if not problem is in action/reducer if it is coming as true i didn't saw any redirection to dashboard

Answer (score 0):

So I needed to set the redirect after I set the `isAuthenticated` boolean. I created a `history.js` file to export `createBrowserHistory`.

**history.js**

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

In my `authReducer.js` file I imported this history file. I then used the `history.push()` method to redirect to another page after setting `isAuthenticated: true`

```
const initialState = {
    isAuthenticated: false
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.LOGIN:
            console.log('[authReducer.js] case: LOGIN')
            history.push('/dashboard')
            return {
                ...state, isAuthenticated: true
            }
        default:
            return initialState
    }
}
```

This documentation helped me [React Router - History](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history)